# how to click on a special coordinate android screen?

Tags: android, click, touch, screen, coordinate

How can i click on a point of android device screen with give it coordinates?
I want to click without touch the screen with my finger.
I want to click with the app.
any idea?
I know we can click and there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to execute `input tap x y` in your app if the coordinate you want to touch is `x`, `y`.

Or you can try to execute this command through `adb` in your PC.